# How can i know which anonymous function its calling another function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, node-modules, rollupjs

I am trying to build an old project it uses `node v8.9` and `npm 5.6` i did a `npm install --save-dev` since `npm` its version `5.6` `package-lock` is being used to install the exact versions of each package.

At the time a lot of the tasks are running ok except one which i dont know which one it is, i am getting the following error:

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'script' of undefined
    at resolveVuePart (C:\mycopy\node_modules\rollup-plugin-vue\dist\rollup-plugin-vue.common.js:74:24)
    at resolveId (C:\mycopy\node_modules\rollup-plugin-vue\dist\rollup-plugin-vue.common.js:103:23)
    at C:\mycopy\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:5915:113
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

how can i know which function is calling or where is starting the call? i checked already:

```
rollup-plugin-vue.common.js:74:24
rollup-plugin-vue.common.js:103:23
rollup.js:5915:113
```

and its clearly that an undefined parameter is being sent, but from where?

Comment: You can't know from only this information.  You will have to add other debugging to figure out what asynchronous operation is triggering this that ultimately leads to `process._tickCallback()`.  FYI, newer versions of node.js have some enhancements in V8 for supplying a bit more information in asynchronous stack traces.  Still might not have everything though.

Comment: A simple and blunt way is to modify rollup.js at 5915:113 to log necessary info.